# PHP XML Caracteres HTML en archivo de salida

Tags: php, xml

Estoy generando un XML en donde al momento de embeber el Certificado este debe ir en cierta codificación que por mas que he buscado no le logrado generar.

Tomando como ejemplo un XML valido he nota que el Certificado embebido presenta en sustitución del **salto de linea**, la codificación: **&#13;**

Por lo cual en mis XMLs he trato de colocar dicho elemento con:

```
$certData= file_get_contents("/ruta/archivo.cer");
wordwrap($certData, 76, "\r\n", true);
```

Pero esto solo me coloca la codificación **&#xD;**, como puedo colocar: **&#13;**??

Aquí XML Valido:

> MIIIoTCCBomgAwIBAgIIW6qCaBJlC8wwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgbQxIzAhBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEW&#13;
>   FGluZm9AYW5kZXNzY2QuY29tLmNvMSMwIQYDVQQDExpDQSBBTkRFUyBTQ0QgUy5BLiBDbGFzZSBJ&#13;

Aquí MI Xml Invalido (salida):

> MIIIoTCCBomgAwIBAgIIW6qCaBJlC8wwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgbQxIzAhBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEW&#xD;
>   FGluZm9AYW5kZXNzY2QuY29tLmNvMSMwIQYDVQQDExpDQSBBTkRFUyBTQ0QgUy5BLiBDbGFzZSBJ&#xD;

Comment: Dado que no has puesto el `XML` real (solo compartes una cadena) y tampoco código `PHP` que lo genera (o las partes relevantes del mismo), me limito en sugerir a que uses un [`CDATA`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es/xml/xml_cdata_sections.htm) para "almacenar" el valor de `$certData`.

Comment: no es necesario mas codigo, ya que el planteamiento es entendible..

Comment: Si necesitas una respuesta con código, te diría que si hace falta más código, en tal caso te recomiendo leer [`Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Como ha dicho @Marcos, hay que ir al origen del problema. ¿A qué se debe que el XML se genere con ese salto de línea?, ¿por qué no vigilas la creación del mismo o la forma en que son tratados los datos para que eso no ocurra?, ¿por qué prefieres aplicar soluciones a medio camino? Si tienes un problema de fondo, resuélvelo en el origen, no arrastres con el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando embebes un XML, si buscas en Google se recomienda con wordwrap colocando la division segun el estandar a integrar, para mi caso no quiero entrar en esta parte de explicarlo porque simplemente el objetivo es llegar el **xml valido**, por lo que el **problema de raiz** (como lo haz mencionado) esta en que no logro escribir ese caracter, ya intente con "\r\n", con solo "\n", y nada... visiblemente es un "salto de linea"

Comment: Lo que me comentas me suena realmente a chino, ¿podrías indicarme alguna referencia creíble donde afirmen que `wordwrap` es para eso? La documentación oficial ni siquiera menciona que `wordwrap` sirva para manejar archivos XML. Si quieres que te ayudemos debes dar más detalles del problema. Me parece que partes de premisas erróneas y que ese es precisamente el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano me queda claro que no esta comprendiendo mi problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reserva de saber cómo estás imprimiendo los caracteres de control, debería funcionar cualquiera entre:

- `wordwrap($certData, 76, chr(13), true);`
- `wordwrap($certData, 76, '&#13;', true);`

Comment: chr(13) fue la solucion....